# uwsim_binary: error while loading shared libraries: libosgbCollision.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ros, libraries, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a solved question. I want to make it public.

After updating a lot of hydro packages, when I run:

```
$ rosrun uwsim uwsim --disableShaders
```

I obtained this:

```
Starting UWSim...
/home/foo/catkin_ws/install/lib/uwsim/uwsim_binary: error while loading shared libraries: libosgbCollision.so.2.00.02: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

As someone wiser than me told me, a few months ago UWSim dependencies were updated for using bullet 2.82 (from there the osgbullet error) and unfortunately the change is not compatible with what had preceded.

I needed to upgrade my simulator version for using this bullet version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/180035/.../install/lib/uwsim/uwsim_binary:-error-while-loading-shared-libraries:-libosgbcollision.so.2.00.02:-cannot-open-shared-object-file:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [a3738294](https://answers.ros.org/users/19245/a3738294/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Solution**: Simply making a *git pull* inside *catkin_ws/src/underwater_simulation* directory should be sufficient (Of course, followed by a *catkin_make install* inside *catkin_ws* directory to compile).

As I didn't modify anything inside that directory I had no problem. If I had done so, it would be possible to have conflict trying to join the new files with the modified ones.

---

Originally posted by [a3738294](https://answers.ros.org/users/19245/a3738294/) with karma: 26 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0